# How to stream, in java, over a key->collection map, where each streamed element is the key and every element in the collection?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I'm trying to flatten the map but not lose the key.

What I would love to have:

```
Map<K, Collection<V>> keyToValuesMap = ...;
Stream.flattenCollection(keyToValuesMap).forEach((k,v) -> print(k, v));
```

Where `v` represents each value in the collection corresponding to each `k`.

---

An equivalent old school java code would be:

```
for (Map.Entry<K, Collection<V>> entry : keyToValuesMap.entrySet())
{
    K k = entry.getKey();

    for (V v : entry.getValue())
    {
         print(k, v);
    }
}
```

---

Please notice that this question is different than just streaming over the values, because the `key` is lost, like this: `keyToValuesMap.entrySet().stream().flatMap(keyValuesEntry -> keyValuesEntry.getValue().stream()).forEach(v -> printJustV(v));`

* The `print` is just an example action on the pair.

* I searched for such an API in [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex), but couldn't find one. I was sure I'd find it there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep the key by creating new `Entry`s:

```
keyToValuesMap.entrySet()
              .stream()
              .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue()
                                     .stream()
                                     .map(v -> new SimpleEntry(entry.getKey(),v)))
              .forEach(entry -> printEntry(entry));
```

Answer (score 8):

This would be alot easier/compact without a stream:

```
map.forEach((k, v) -> v.forEach(e -> print(k, e)));
```

Comment: While the result is correct you are not flattening the values, you are iterating on the elements using a different syntax of standard for

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO I think the better question is why flatten it in the first place if all you want to do is print each key and each element of the collection? I'd only consider using a streaming approach to flatten the result if and only if I had to perform some further refinement to my query via `groupingBy`, `toMap` to perform more complex aggregations. this approach is 1) more efficient, 2) more concise, 3) more readable etc...

Comment: I found this solution pretty elegant (*upvote from me*)

Comment: Yes the solution is elegant anyway... I read the question and I thought that flatten was in the title, but was only in the description of what the op tried. +1 for me

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO yeah sometimes people get too caught up on the description from the OP but actually, the solution is a lot simpler than that. appreciated!

Comment: Nice one. This solution may be problematic in the case where the "end stream" is needed, like passing it as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static <K, V> void print(Map<K, Collection<V>> map) {
    map.entrySet().stream()
       .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream().map(value -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(entry.getKey(), value)))
       .forEach(entry -> print(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
}
```

Comment: Why the `collect(Collectors.toList())`? See Eran's solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53762511/435605

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you you'd want to use Streams for something as simple as this.

You can still just create a helper method somewhere in a utility class:

```
public static <K, V> void forEachElement(
    Map<? extends K, ? extends Collection<? extends V>> map, 
    BiConsumer<? super K, ? super V> action
){
    for (Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends Collection<? extends V>> entry : map.entrySet()){
        K k = entry.getKey();
        for (V v : entry.getValue()) {
             action.accept(k, v);
        }
    }
}
```

Which can then be called like this:

```
SomeUtilClass.forEachElement(keyToValuesMap, (k, v) -> print(k, v));
```